# Can Selenium web driver have access to javascript global variables?

Tags: javascript, python, django, selenium

Hi: I'm writing tests for django with javascript and I was wondering if the Selenium webdriver can access a javascript global variable. `mypage` has a script that has a global variable I'd like to access. Is it possible? Thanks!

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

class TestEditorSelenium(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = WebDriver()

    def test_mytest(self):
        self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/mypage/'))
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to that with code similar to the below:

```
browser.execute_script("return globalVar;")
```

Comment: `print self.driver.execute_script("return globalVar;")` worked...thanks!

Comment: Interesting.. I can get an expected value `execute_script("return window.name;")` or `execute_script("return window.location;")` but not for `execute_script("return window;")` The last one returns an empty array for me....