# How can I scrape a Highcharts.charts.series.data with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, highcharts

I'm having trouble scrapping this webstite : https://en.macromicro.me/collections/4356/freight/44756/drewry-world-container-index

I need to get  Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data to  Highcharts.charts[0].series[8].data. In the website I already located the elements. Key and y.

I'm using databricks and python. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks!

EDIT:

I had several attemps I found but none of them are working for me.

[image: First attemp]

The main issue is I cant get any element of the Highchart.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error scraping Highcharts in Python with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62834695/error-scraping-highcharts-in-python-with-selenium)

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Thank you for your comment. That actually doesnt help me.

Comment: Ok, that's fine @BorisRendón. Your code looks valid in any case, and the error you get looks like a file system permission issue, with geckodriver not being able to write its log.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Do you know a way I could use beautiful soup instead of selenium?

Comment: Selenium appears to be the less complex solution in this case. Did you try using Chrome/chromedriver instead of Firefox/geckodriver?

Comment: Hi @Boris Rendón, I am not sure if your script is correct since the `return` keyword can only be used inside functions. Please try to use `driver.execute_script('Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].options.data')` or `driver.execute_script('return Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].options.data')` in one line.