# Python - How can I scrape with bs4 a javascript code)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying to scrape out a value from a html that is a javascript. There is alot of javascript in the code but I just want to be able to print out this one:

```
var spConfig=newProduct.Config({
  "attributes": {
    "531": {
      "id": "531",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "18",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "128709"
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "40 1\/2",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "120151"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "33",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "120152"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "36",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "128710"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "42",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "125490"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  "Id": "120153",

});
```

So I started by doing a code that looks like:

```
test = bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
print(test)
```

The output I am getting is pretty huge so I am not able to post it all here but one of them is the javascript as I mentioned at the top and I want to print out only `var spConfig=newProduct.Config`.

How am I able to do that, to be able to just print out `var spConfig=newProduct.Config....`  which I later can use json.loads that convert it to a json where I later on can scrape it more easier?

*For any question or something I haven't explained well. I will apprecaite everything in the comment where I can improve myself aswell here in stackoverflow! :)*

EDIT:

More example of what bs4 prints out for javascripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">varoptionsPrice=newProduct.Options({
  "priceFormat": {
    "pattern": "%s\u00a0\u20ac",
    "precision": 2,
    "requiredPrecision": 2,
    "decimalSymbol": ",",
    "groupSymbol": "\u00a0",
    "groupLength": 3,
    "integerRequired": 1
  },
  "showBoths": false,
  "idSuffix": "_clone",
  "skipCalculate": 1,
  "defaultTax": 20,
  "currentTax": 20,
  "tierPrices": [

  ],
  "tierPricesInclTax": [

  ],
  "swatchPrices": null
});</script>,
<script type="text/javascript">var spConfig=newProduct.Config({
  "attributes": {
    "531": {
      "id": "531",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "18",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "128709"
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "40 1\/2",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "120151"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "33",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "120152"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "36",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "128710"
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "42",
          "hunter": "0",
          "products": [
            "125490"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  "Id": "120153"
});</script>,
<scripttype="text/javascript">document.observe('dom:loaded',
function(){
  varswatchesConfig=newProduct.ConfigurableSwatches(spConfig);
});</script>
```

EDIT update 2:

```
try:
    product_li_tags = bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
except Exception:
    product_li_tags = []


for product_li_tag in product_li_tags:
   try:
        pat = "product.Config\((.+)\);"
        json_str = re.search(pat, product_li_tag, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
        print(json_str)
   except:
       pass

#json.loads(json_str)
print("Nothing")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup - extract json from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852187/beautifulsoup-extract-json-from-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.text` function to get the content within each tag.  Then, if you know that you want to grab the code that specifically starts with "`varoptionsPrice`", you can filter for that:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml, 'lxml')

script_blocks = soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
special_code = ''
for s in script_blocks:
    if s.text.strip().startswith('varOptionsPrice'):
        special_code = s.text
        break

print(special_code)
```

EDIT: To answer your question in the comments, there are a couple of different ways of extracting the part of the text that has the JSON.  You could pass it through a regexp to grab everything between the first left parentheses and before the `);` at the end.  Though if you want to avoid regexp completely, you could do something like:

```
json_stuff = special_code[special_code.find('(')+1:special_code.rfind(')')]
```

Then to make a usable dictionary out of it:

```
import json
j = json.loads(json_stuff)
print(j['defaultTax'])  # This should return a value of 20
```

Comment: Yesss! This right here!!! However, What if we want to create that s.text to a json if it finds of course?

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere, I've updated my comments to answer the JSON part.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of possible 3 options - which one you use might depend on the size of the project and how flexible you need it to be

- Use Regex to extract the objects from the script (fastest, least flexible)
- Use ANTLR or similar (eg. [pyjsparser](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/pyjsparser)) to parse the js grammar
- Use Selenium or other headless browsers that can interpret the JS for you. With this option, you can use selenium to execute a call to get the value of the variable [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455130/can-selenium-web-driver-have-access-to-javascript-global-variables)

#### Regex Example (#1)

```
>>> script_body = """
    var x=product.Config({
        "key": {"a":1}
});
"""
>>> pat = "product.Config\((.+)\);"
>>> json_str = re.search(pat, script_body, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
>>> json.loads(json_str)
{'key': {'a': 1}}
>>> json.loads(json_str)['key']['a']
1
```

Comment: Oh hmm. Because the value is there when I scrape the whole html.parse. The value is inside `script type="'text/javascript"`. My idea was that maybe it is possible scrape it like you usually do with bs4 but I assume that is not possible?

Comment: Any way you could post more output from the test variable? Just to see exactly what the structure is.

Comment: AFAIK bs4 will not be able to interpret the JS syntax so the script body as a string is as far as it will take you.

Comment: @gtalarico I just saw you example and I thought I might give it a go but I couldn't figure out what "s" stands for in json_str?

Comment: sorry that was a typo in the example - `s` was `script_body` 
I have corrected the example

Comment: Wouldn't that code work if I print out all `bs4 javascript` and then try to search for `Product.Config` ? Just an idea

Comment: That's the idea ^

Comment: You need to adjust the regex expressions to match "newProduct.Config"